How to get ToolStripComboBox from sender in an event?
I am trying to get the Name of the ToolstripCombox that triggered the event.
Unfortunately it is not possible to cast the sender as a ToolStripComboBox but only as ComboBox.
How do I get the Name of the ToolStripComboBox which is the Owner of the ComboBox?
private void ToolStripComboBox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    ToolStripComboBox toolStripComboBox = comboBox.????;
    string name = toolStripComboBox.Name;

}

The events are triggered from the ComboBox and not the ToolStripComboBox.
ToolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DropDown += new EventHandler(ToolStripComboBox_DropDown);
ToolStripComboBox2.ComboBox.DropDown += new EventHandler(ToolStripComboBox_DropDown);


it is not possible to cast the sender as a ToolStripComboBox... False. It is ToolStripComboBox and you can't cast it as ComboBox. What do you get from var tscb = sender as ToolStripComboBox;? The inner cbox is accessible through the tscb.ComboBox property.

@dr.null, I am getting null

Not possible unless you're doing something wrong. For example, subscribing the handler to events of other items. Use your debugger to find out and start with var t = sender.GetType().Name;. Add a break point and see what you get.

I have added some extra information on the events...

ah.. that's why. Remove the ComboBox parts. ToolStripComboBox1.DropDown += ToolStripComboBox_DropDown;. The cbox events are shadowed in the base class.

If I do that then I have an issue with my second event which is SelectionChangeCommitted which is only available for ComboBox and not ToolStripComboBox.

SelectedIndexChanged does not work for you?

The problem I experience with SelectedIndexChanged is that it fires already when the ToolStripComboBox is dropping down resulting in the first value in the dropdownlist being registered as the selected value.

That happens in the data-bound scenarios. In this case, before hooking the events up, bind the cbox to the datasource, set the SelectedIndex property to -1, and lastly, add the handlers. If you still need to use your code as is, use the workaround commented to @NeilT's answer.

Thanks.
Considering ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
How do I get the value of Owner property from comboBox ?

The owner is the parent which can be of type ToolStripDropDownMenu or ToolStrip depending on who is hosting the ToolStripComboBox item. Perhaps you mean the OwnerItem? Then it's ToolStripItem ownerItem = (comboBox.Parent as ToolStripDropDownMenu).OwnerItem;. See also this answer if you mean that. No? Then please edit your question to include where that cbox is inserted and what exactly do you need to achieve. You also can derive a new class to raise the SelectionChangeCommitted event....etc.

No, if I put a break at the ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender; and I expand all the properties then I see an Owner property just like Items, Dock etc property.

Inheritance - derive types to create more specialized behavior.

You can cast (safely) to ToolStripComboBox, something like this:
    private void ToolStripComboBox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is ToolStripComboBox toolStripComboBox))
        {
            // Handle error
            throw new Exception();
        }

        var name = toolStripComboBox.Name;
    }

(The type safety check might be unnecessary in your case.)
Update (after question edit):
As per your comment on this answer (and @dr.null's comments on the question), you are subscribing to the ComboBox's events . Instead, subscribe directly to the ToolStripComboBox events, like this:
ToolStripComboBox1.DropDown += new EventHandler(ToolStripComboBox_DropDown);

Re your most recent comment: if you need the ComboBox's SelectionChangeCommitted event then yes, you will need to subscribe to the ComboBox event directly. In this case, you might be able to access the containing ToolStripComboBox via comboBox.Parent or comboBox.Container, with a suitable cast.
Failing that, you could populate a Dictionary mapping each ComboBox to its containing ToolStripComboBox during initialisation. This is a heavy-handed approach, though.

Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.

Then the sender was not a ToolStripComboBox, despite what the name of the method suggests. You might like to put a breakpoint in the method and check the type of the sender (e.g. via sender.GetType() or sender.GetType().FullName in the Immediate window).

See my added code above. The event is on the ToolstripComboBox.ComboBox...

Try ToolStripComboBox par = (cmb.Parent as ToolStripDropDownMenu).Items.OfType<ToolStripComboBox>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Control == sender); as workaround.
